# Displaying webpages without webview

Tags: android, web-services, webview, httpclient, html

Actually i want to displaying webpages with proxy in it, i have problem using webview. Is there any other way beside webview to displaying webpages in android? like httpclient or httpurlconnection? The using of proxy is just hardcode in coding, i have the proxy and username. I know there is a way to get data from string code, and my apps detect  my proxy by using some defaulthttpclient method. But using that way is just displaying string in webview, not displaying webpages that i want.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string representing HTML content you can always display it like

```
browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webkit);

browser.loadData("<html><body>Hello, world!</body></html>",
          "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: yeah its just same (using webView).

you declare that browser as a webView.
and the loadData is just using for loading the data before the url load. 

basically what you are saying is still the same (using webview).

but thanks by the way

Answer (score 0):

webpages are basically text files. when you request a web page. you are making a httppost. you have to make http post and later on you have to parse content of respond. And with parsed content you can recreate new androıd items. But first look of that this is lots of work. Like writing a browser from scratch.